# Hiding IdentityServer4 behind Ocelot gateway

Tags: docker, identityserver4, ocelot

I'm trying to resolve a bigger issue by splitting it into smaller bits. The first problem is that i don't know how to hide properly. for the purpose of this post, i've created a simple demo app that gets deployed to docker (available on [github](https://github.com/przemekwojcik/OcelotIdentity)). It has two microservices inside: OcelotGateway (OcelotIdentity project) deployed to localhost:7060 and IdentityServer microservice (Identity project) deployable to localhost:7050. Here's my ocelot configuration file:

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{route}",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/identity/{route}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Options", "Post" ],
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "ServiceName": "identity"
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId",
    "AdministrationPath": "/administration"
  }
}
```

So i expect to see IdentityServer's quickstart page at localhost:7060/identity, but i get 404 instead. This page works fine when i'm reaching it directly at Identity server's url (localhost:7050).

Answer (score 0):

You probably already figured out the answer, but just for future generations; I suppose the problem is your catch-all, that expects something like `/identity/something` to be passed to `/something`.

To display the quick-start page, you should define another re-route, that only catches `/identity` and forwards to `/`. Then, no `something` is required and the re-route should work just fine.

Also, the scheme should better be `https`.